# How to add edit functionality in datatable with bootstrap and MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have done following code and now iI want to add edit column in Bootstrap Datatable with server side functionality in MVC and Bootstrap. Finally I want proper CRUD operation, so how can I approach for this?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        var assetListVM;
        $(function () {
            assetListVM = {
                dt: null,

                init: function () {
                    dt = $('#assets-data-table').DataTable({
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "processing": true,
                        "ajax": {
                            "url": "@Url.Action("Get","Asset")"
                        },
                        "columns": [
                            { "title": "ID", "data": "ID", "searchable": true },
                            { "title": "Name", "data": "Name", "searchable": true },
                            { "title": "City", "data": "City", "searchable": true },
                            { "title": "EmpCode", "data": "EmpCode", "searchable": true },
                            { "title": "DOJ", "data": "DOJ", "searchable": true },
                            { "title": "Address", "data": "Address" },
                            { "title": "DOB", "data": "DOB" }
                        ],
                        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],

                    });
                }
            }

            // initialize the datatables
            assetListVM.init();                
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Look into DataTables Editor. It's built for stuff like this. https://editor.datatables.net/

Comment: thanks @rob  i got the solution.